# Why is my registered message not being triggered (across processes)

Tags: message-queue

I have a Visual basic application (.NET) and I have set up all the declarations for registering messages and sending them:

```
    Private Const WM_DELETE_EVENT_STRING As String = "WM_xxx_DELETE_EVENT"
    Private Const WM_INSERT_EVENT_STRING As String = "WM_xxx_INSERT_EVENT"

    Private Shared WM_DELETE_EVENT As UInteger = Posting.PostingFunctions.RegisterWindowMessage(WM_DELETE_EVENT_STRING)
    Private Shared WM_INSERT_EVENT As UInteger = Posting.PostingFunctions.RegisterWindowMessage(WM_INSERT_EVENT_STRING)

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(ByVal lpString As String) As UInteger
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

The handle I post with is of type IntPtr. I provide it from the calling process by using:

```
    strNumber.Format(_T("%d"), theApp.GetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd());
    WritePrivateProfileString(_T("Settings"), _T("HwndExternalApp"), strNumber, strINI);
```

What I do is read it from the INI file in my VB process:

```
    m_hExternalApp = CLng((oIni.IniReadValueInt("Settings", "HwndExternalApp"))
```

My calling process is MDI application. And I added the same two registered messages to the CMainFrame class.

And finally, here is the way I call the VB process:

```
    <snipped out CreateProcess code>
    DWORD WaitResult;
    do
    {
        WaitResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,
            // only 1 wait object
            &processInformation.hProcess, // worker thread
            FALSE,   // stop if any
            INFINITE,  // no timeout
            QS_ALLINPUT);
        if (WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            // Handle windows message
            MSG Msg;
            while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
            }
        }
    } while (WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1);
    ASSERT(WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

I confirm that the VB handlers are actually being fired, but the C++ app does not seem to process them. So:

1. Am I passing the right handle to my INI file for the VB process to use?
2. Am I using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects correctly?

I am in deep water here and not sure where I have gone wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Andrew

Comment: You did not show the VB code that is sending the messages, or the C++ code that is registering and handling the messages. Also, your `do/while` loop should be looping while `WaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0` instead of while `WaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1`.

Comment: VB: SendMessage(hWnd, WM_INSERT_EVENT, iPercent, 0)

C++: The regular ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE etc.

I did a TRACE of all the messages in the inner WHILE loop and it was not showing the messages I had posted.

Is it because the VB program was a console application?

I detected WM_TIMER was still firing so wrote what I needed to display into a text file and then read it in OnTimer. That works fine for me.

I would show you my code if you think you can help explain why my SendMessage was not being triggered. I confirm the HWND was the right as I could call to ::MoveWindow on it.

Comment: `SendMessage()` does not put the message in the target window's message queue, it delivers the message straight to the target window procedure, so your message loop will not see the messages. Only `PostMessage()` goes through the message queue. Your `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` handler should be seeing the message, provided it is attached to the window that the message is being sent to.

Comment: I did also try PostMessage. The handle I passed was for the CMainFrame class. That class has the correct handlers etc. I will check again.